# In JQuery, how to display error only according to the value of one form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a form dynamic using JQuery, I want to display an Error message and the color with it when the user enter less than 4 characters in the **2nd** input of the form.

Hre is my code:

```
  <form>

  <label for="text">Text </label>
  <input id="text" type="text">

  <label for="text2">Text 2</label>
  <input id="text2" type="text">

  <button type="submit">Send</button>

  <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger" style="display:none">

      <h4>Error!</h4>

      You have to enter less than 4 caracters in the 2nde input ! 

   </div>

  </form>

<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function() {
      if($("input:text2").val().length < 4) {
        $("div.form-group").addClass("has-error");
        $("div.alert").show("slow").delay(4000).hide("slow");
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

But it seems that only when the value of the 1st input is less than 4 letters the Error message appears, but I want it to appear when the **2nd** input is less than 4 letters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$("input:text2");
```

did you mean:

```
$("#text2")
```

?  I'm not sure what the former means, but the latter is an ID selector for the 2nd text input's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the id selector in jquery

```
if($("#text2").val().length < 4)
```

```js
    $("form").on("submit", function() {
      if($("#text2").val().length < 4) {
        $("div.form-group").addClass("has-error");
        $("div.alert").show("slow").delay(4000).hide("slow");
        return false;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <label for="text">Text </label>
  <input id="text" type="text">

  <label for="text2">Text 2</label>
  <input id="text2" type="text">

  <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>

  <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger" style="display:none">

      <h4>Error!</h4>

      You have to enter less than 4 caracters in the 2nde input ! 

   </div>

  </form>
```